# How does a VS Code extension publisher know that its domain has been verified?

Tags: vscode-extensions, marketplace

I encountered some problems when publishing my VS Code extension:

I applied for domain verification for publisher based on [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#verify-a-publisher) and configured relevant DNS records. "Your request to verify the domain is submitted to the marketplace team for processing." is displayed on the publisher's details page. The document stated that it would be processed within 5 working days. I submitted this application on February 29, 2024, but the details page still shows the same words so far (March 8, 2024).

How do I know the domain verification has passed? Due to my company policy, I want my extension to be domain verified when publishing it

I tried configuring DNS records and submitted it to the marketplace team for review. I expected that there would be verification-related updates on the publisher details page in 5 working days, but there is none now.

Comment: There is one more day to wait. And then you can contact the support team when needed, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/779 Not something Stack Overflow can resolve for you.